# Do mongoDB SystemIndexes vary with database contents, or are they static configuration?

Tags: json, mongodb, file, indexing, system

We are using full text search on mongo 2.6. To this we create the indexes using db.ensureIndex commands. Then we save these systemIndexes so developers may import test data with the appropriate indexes into a clean database. We have used the following strategy to import our fulltext search indexes into a clean database:

mongoimport -d krypton -c system.indexes --jsonArray --drop --file deploy/systemIndexes.js

The systemIndexes.js file has been generated using a mongoexport command, and it looks like this:

[{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "*id*", "ns" : "krypton.finder" },{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "loc" : "2d" } ....

Do these systemIndexes vary as documents are added to the database? My guess is no, they are not, that systemIndexes represent static configuration (which column(s) on which collection(s) is indexed, and so on.

Am I correct? But if I am correct, where--in what files--does mongo maintain the actual indexing of the documents that are already in, or being added to, the database?

I would assume that these files will increase in size as new documents are added to the database.

All hints or perspectives are welcome.
Thanks in advance!

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `system.indexes` collection just contains the index definitions.  You will get a similar output if you just use `mongodump` to dump out a collection, there will be a `BSON` file with the data in it and a metadata `JSON` file that contains the index definitions (I would recommend this method rather than using `mongoexport` generally by the way).  By exporting the `system.indexes` collection  as you describe, you are basically doing this manually.

When you restore the definitions to system.indexes (either manually, or with mongorestore), an index build is kicked off whenever you insert to `system.indexes`.  If there is a small amount of data (or none), then this will complete quickly and as documents are added the indexes will be updated too - for large data sets, this would take a significant amount of time.

In terms of storage, the indexes are stored within the data files, not in separate files elsewhere - they are stored in separate extents within those files, but that is not something that is exposed outside the database.  There is a long standing feature request to allow for indexes to be separate ([SERVER-965](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-965)) but that is not currently scheduled for implementation.

Hence, if you wish to deliver intact indexes you will need to deliver the data also, they cannot be delivered separately.  If you want to deliver both, then you can just need to give the developers the database files: dbname.ns, dbname.0, dbname.1, dbname.2 etc.  Stop writes (for consistency), tar those files up (or use your archive method of choice) and make them available to your developers - each database can be considered self-contained.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is hugely helpful.

Comment: No problem :) - It's worth noting that the MMS Backup service (free to try, paid for proper use, and available as an on-premise solution) effectively does this for you - each database snapshot (which can be created to arbitrary points in time if needed) is delivered as a complete set of data files (so data and indexes), and would effectively automate this entire process for you: https://mms.mongodb.com/